# Sum of squares of natural numbers and geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

$$S_n = 0\cdot4^0 + 1^2\cdot4^1 + 2^2\cdot4^2 + 3^2\cdot4^3 + \ldots + n^2\cdot4^n$$

ie- $S_n =  \sum\limits_{i=0}^ni^2\cdot4^i$.

I need help with this problem. I integrated it using ILATE rule and found the leading term of this series of the order $O(n^2\cdot4^n)$. However, I want the exact sum of this series since I want the co-efficient of the leading term of this series.

I am working on a recurrence relation problem and after unfolding the recurrence relation, I got this series. However, I am not able to think of an approach to solve this series.

Comment: Hint:  Sums like this can be addressed by (repeatedly) differentiating the geometric series $\sum_{i=0}^kx^i$ and adjusting the terms as needed.

Comment: I added MathJax to your question and fixed up the tags.

Comment: $f(x) := \sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x} \implies
f'(x) =\sum_{k=1}^n kx^{k-1} = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\right)$. Multiply by $x$ then differentiate one more time.

Comment: Thanks @AsemAbdelraouf and lulu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$S_n(x) =  \sum\limits_{i=0}^n i^2x^i= \sum\limits_{i=0}^n\big[ i(i-1)+i\big]x^i$$
$$S_n(x) =x^2 \sum\limits_{i=0}^n i(i-1)x^{i-2}+x\sum\limits_{i=0}^n ix^{i-1}$$
$$S_n(x) =x^2 \left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n x^i \right)''+x\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^n x^i \right)'$$
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n x^i=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$  When done, let $x=4$.